# Magento checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, shipping-methods

I attached a new option to the delivery method, which the customer can choose. The question is, which is the best solution to store the value of that custom field in the form of the transport method.
[image: I post a capture of my checkout page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding custom attribute fields to magento is a painful experience in both magento 1 and magento 2.

It's something I've had to do a few times but no client wants the same fields in the same place.

If you go extension route this handles field visibility and saving. Plus providing you haven't changed much in admin values will come through there too.

https://www.fmeextensions.com/magento-additional-checkout-attributes-fields.html